# Why this program of stacking using linked list is not working?

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

Code compiles just fine but when i try to pop or display the pushed integer values it crashes ! Thanx in advance for helping me out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
 {
int data;
 struct node* next;
}*top=NULL;

 void push(int);
  void pop();
 void display();



 void main()
{
int choice,value;
while(1){
printf("\n-----MENU-----\n");
printf("\n1. Push\n2. Pop\n3. Display\n4. Exit");
printf("\nEnter your choice\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
switch(choice)
{
    case 1:  printf("Enter a number to push\n");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    push(value);
    break;
    case 2: pop();
    break;
    case 3: display();
    break;
    case 4: exit(0);
}}
getch();
 }
```

FUNCTION TO PUSH A VALUE

```
void push (int value)
{
struct node*newnode;
newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newnode->data=value;
if(top==NULL){
newnode->next=NULL;
}
else
{


  newnode->next=top;
  top=newnode;
    printf("Insertion successful\n");
    }
   }
```

FUNCTION TO POP A VALUE FROM LIST

```
    void pop()
    {

   if (top==NULL)
  {
  printf("Nothing to delete");
 }
 else{
struct node *temp=top;
printf("Deleted element %d", temp->data);
top=temp->next;
free(temp);
}}
```

FUNCTION TO DISPLAY THE STACKED ELEMENTS

```
 void display()
{
if(top==NULL)
{
    printf("List is empty\n");
}
else
{
    struct node *temp=top;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d ----->NULL", temp->data);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Use a debugger. That is the best way to debug such issues.

Comment: Add ending `\n` in `printf` (or call `fflush(NULL);`). Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). **Use the debugger** `gdb` to run the program step by step. Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: `if(top==NULL){
newnode->next=NULL;` --> `if(top==NULL){
newnode->next=NULL; top = newnode;` or `newnode->next=top;
  top=newnode;
    printf("Insertion successful\n");
    }` --> `newnode->next=top; }
  top=newnode;
    printf("Insertion successful\n");`

Comment: SO is not the place where other people would debug & do your homework. And finding bugs is an essential (but difficult) skill when programming. So you need to do your homework, and learn how to use the debugger. BTW your *fix-my-code* question is **off-topic** here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch not to be rude but it is so not off-topic and i don't want you to find the bug i just want to know if i did something that should not be done.

Comment: It is off-topic here on SO, and there is even a menu element to close it. It is one of the most common reasons for questions having mostly code to be closed. I voted to close it, and I believe your question will be closed within a day. And **debugging skills** (both know-how in your head, and ability to use debuggers like `gdb`) **are part of what *you* should learn**.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you so much you are the best. This is the most precise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `top` after insertion of the first element, change to (also never forget to verify your allocation status):

```
void push (int value) {
  struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if (newnode==NULL) { /* error */ }
  newnode->data=value;
  newnode->next=top;
  top=newnode;
  printf("Insertion successful\n");
}
```